# How do I copy input from one textbox to another via checkbox using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm cleaning up a simple form that has a Start Date textbox and an End Date textbox. I want to add a checkbox in between these fields that the user can check if the End Date is the same as the Start Date, so when they check it, the Start Date input value (e.g., 04/01/09) will automagically appear in the End Date textbox, so they don't have to type in the same date twice. Does that make sense?

BTW, I'm using the sexy jquery datepicker UI, and it's sweet, but I just can't figure out the above problem.

I know there's a simple solution (event handler?) but I'm stumped.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$("#checkboxId").click(copyDate);

function copyDate()
{
   var start=$("#startDate").val();
   if (this.checked==true)
     $("#endDate").val(start);
}
```

Replace the 'id's with your own field ids.

Comment: What if someone tabs to the checkbox and hits space (i.e., checks it without clicking)?

Comment: Good point, he can add another event using $("#checkboxId").change(copyDate);

Comment: Sorry to pick this up so late, but how exactly would I be able to toggle the checkbox, so that if the user changes their mind that the end date is different from the start date. Some sort of toggle? How would that work with the above code snippet? Thnx.

Answer (score 4):

Simple hack to solve your problem.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="js/jquery.js" ></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="startdate" id="startdate" value=""/>
        <input type="text" name="enddate" id="enddate" value=""/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checker" id="checker" />
    </form>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $("input#checker").bind("click",function(o){
                if($("input#checker:checked").length){
                    $("#enddate").val($("#startdate").val());
                }else{
                    $("#enddate").val("");
                }
            });
        }
    );
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```